# create a username validator without spaces

Tags: flutter, dart

how do I create a validator for the username, so when the user fills in the username and there is a space then there is an alert ??
right now my code is like this

```
                       TextFormField(
                            controller: txtUsername,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Username",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                            ),
                            validator: (usernameInput) {
                              if (usernameInput.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Username partner tidak boleh kosong';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (usernameInput) {
                              username = usernameInput;
                            },
                          ),
```

I tried using regex but I can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `.contains()` method.

For example:

```
validator: (usernameInput) {
    if (usernameInput.isEmpty) {
        return 'Username partner tidak boleh kosong';
    }
    else if(usernameInput.contains(' ')) {
        return 'Username cannot contains spaces';
    }
    return null;
},
```

Comment: In addition you can also use RegExp if you want to. Check out the Documentation here: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/String/contains.html